# How to get a current user location in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, localization, geolocation

There is a website that support shops information like food,drink,golf,spa.
This websites provide information on Thailand, Hongkong, Singapore and Cambodia.
If a user from Thailand connect this website. The default menu will be set to Thailand.
If a user from Hongkong use this website. We will set default menu to Hongkong.
If a user from others country that is not in the list. the default will be set to Thailand.

What is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Google Loader https://developers.google.com/loader/.

Similiar question [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053624/getting-user-location-with-google-loader-clientlocation-working-for-me-but-not-o).  The accepted answer even has an example page.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the location of incoming request by the following service. Which will give you country and city.

```
http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=207.46.197.32
```

There is a open source which will do the same for you, please have a look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28363/How-to-convert-IP-address-to-country-name)

If you need more then visit [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2665196/tracking-ip-address-and-country-nameasp-net)