# How do i find out a website user's geolocation in .net application?

Tags: .net, web, geolocation, location

I want a way to determine the location (at least to a city level) of my website user, how do i do that in .net application? Is there any free api for that?

Answer (score 0):

Can´t you use an client javascript in your html?
http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407921/how-to-get-a-current-user-location-in-asp-net) question. Answers contain multiple libraries which satisfies your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for IP geolocation, you could use [MaxMind's GeoLite2](http://dev.maxmind.com/geoip/geoip2/geolite2/) with the [GeoIP2 .NET reader](http://maxmind.github.io/GeoIP2-dotnet/).